# Implications of using Linux's Kbuild infrastructure in proprietary software

Tags: licensing, gpl, gpl-2, gnu, linux-kernel

We have our own proprietary software that we are developing for commercial business. We want to sell the software and we do not have any problem in distributing the source code to our customers. Due to the lack of good build infrastructure and complexity of the software, it has become difficult to manage and has lost its readability.

An easy way to manage this is by making use of Kbuild as is done in Linux and U-Boot. This means using (and customizing) Kbuild and Kconfig specific files (and few modified Makefiles) to compile our software.

I went through all the FAQs for GPL v2 (https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0-faq.html) but I'm not able to make what implications would be of using Kbuild infrastructure in my proprietary software. Can anyone help me in understanding them?

Comment: This is a great question? why why this downvoted? please add a comment when you do so.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm not able to make what implications would be of using Kbuild infrastructure in my proprietary software.

The reason why you are not able to make what the implications would be is there **are absolutely no implications whatsoever**. The Kernel build system is under the same license as the Kernel e.g. the GPL, but the fact that it is GPL or else does not matter here.

Using the Kbuild scripts -- or any other build script -- to build any kind of software has no bearing on the software being built in 99.99% of the cases.

The analogy would be using a text editor to write programs: the license of Microsoft Word does not impact the license of a document you write with Word.

Or the EPL license of the Eclipse IDE does not impact the license of any code written with Eclipse.